# convert String into integer in java script without using any built in functions

Tags: javascript

Is there any trick to convert string to integer in javascript without using any function and methods?

```js
var s = "5"
console.log(typeof(s)) // out put is string 
console.log(typeof(parseInt(s))) // i want out put which is number with out using parseInt() or other functions for optimizing code.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: my question is different first read full question i know this type of question was asked before

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/convert-a-string-to-an-integer-in-javascript.

Comment: there is an oneother answer with using (-) which cast string in to integer

Comment: @Rajesh Please don't stuck to the example code, the question says "_convert string to integer_" Any string ...

Comment: @Teemu So for `s="5.5"`, expected output should be `5` and not `5.5` as `+s` returns... Damn! I didn't think of this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is a most effective way to convert string into int without using any built in function have a look at code. Thank you:)

```js
var s = "5"
var i = s - 0
console.log(typeof(i)) // you will get a number without using any built in function... because (-) will cast string in to number
```

Comment: I find much more in this explanation.

Answer (score 6):

You can cast the string to number using unary plus (`+`). This will do nothing much beside some code optimization.

```js
var s = "5"
s = +s;
console.log(typeof(s), s);

var s = "5.5"
s = +s;
console.log(typeof(s), s);
```

Comment: `var s = "5.5"` What now?

Comment: @TakitIsy Exactly, and that's not what was asked ("_convert string to __integer___"). It doesn't matter, though, since OP has accepted an answer which doesn't do what they actually asked for ...

Comment: @Teemu I agree, but well… I guess the OP meant *number* and not *integer* anyway. For many, *integers* are just *numbers*.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using bit-wise operator `s|0`. This will convert value to integer. However, this will also convert floating values to integer.

```js
var s = "5"
var y = s|0;
console.log(typeof(y), s, y);

var s = "5.5"
var y = s|0;
console.log(typeof(y), s, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you are searching "whole logic" to convert string to int then you have to ***find ASCII code for each alphabet in string and then convert it to integer and make sum of all*** 48 to 57 are ASCII codes are for number 0 to 1. Below is example code

```
let parseINT = (b) => b.split("").map((e,i) => {
    let value = e.charCodeAt(0) - 48;
    return value * [...Array(((i - b.length) * -1)).keys()].reduce((a, b) => a > 0 ? (a * 10) : 1, 0);
}).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

or short form will be like

```
let parseINT = (b) => b.split("").map((e,i) => ((e.charCodeAt(0)  <= 57 ? e.charCodeAt(0) : 48) - 48) * [...Array(((i - b.length) * -1)).keys()].reduce((a, b) => a > 0 ? (a * 10) : 1, 0)).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```